# Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program in VS2005 after installing VS2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-2.0

I currently have a client that requires working on a project in Visual Studio 2005 which includes several class projects and two websites. After installing VS 2012 RC, I now receive the following error on any asp.net project, existing or newly created default website templates. Only VS 2005 was affected, 2010 still works correctly.

I've uninstalled VS 2012, and uninstalled then reinstalled the following, to no avail: .NET 2.0 Framework, VS 2005

```
Server Error in '/WebSite1' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidProgramException: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 


[InvalidProgramException: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.]
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager..ctor() +0
   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.EnsureInitialized() +236
   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.OnEnsureInitialized(Object state) +4
   System.ServiceModel.PartialTrustHelpers.PartialTrustInvoke(ContextCallback callback, Object state) +52
   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.SafeEnsureInitialized() +73
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule.ProcessRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) +220
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +68
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +348




--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5466; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5459
```